# Unable to receive response data from @ExceptionHalndler method

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have deployed Restful Web Serivce on the server and accessing it from Client application.

I am using JSON to communicate data between services & client.

Normal flow is working perfect.

But,in case of Exception, I am able to receive HTTP STATUS & reason for Exception but not receiving Response Body.

Here is my Exception Handler

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,reason="Unable to fetch data")      

public @ResponseBody String handle(MyException ex)

    {
        ErrorInfo error = new ErrorInfo();   
        String response = null;
        error.setErrorStatus(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));  
        error.setErrorCode(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));   // TODO Need to store Application specific error code
        error.setErrorMessage("Communication Error : Unable to fetch conference data");                  // TODO Need to get from message resource file
        error.setDeveloperMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage());


        response = utilities.fromBeanToJson(error);
        System.out.println("***Response : " + response);
        return response;   // Not able to receive this info
    }
```

Actual Response :

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Unable to fetch conference data</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Unable to fetch data</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error (Unable to fetch data) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.29</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `reason` from `@ResponseStatus`? From the Javadoc of `@ResponseStatus` it seems that when it's set, the response is considered complete and should not be written to any further

Comment: Yes, it is workin after removing 'reason'. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I added it as answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `reason` from `@ResponseStatus`.
This is needed because from the the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html?is-external=true) of `@ResponseStatus` we can see:

> The reason to be used for the response.
>
> If this element is not set,
>   it will default to the standard status message for the status code.
>   Note that due to the use of {@code HttpServletResponse.sendError(int,
>   String)}, the response will be considered complete and should not be
>   written to any further.